# SELECT data FROM two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, union, database-table

**What I have:** The next structure:

**table_zero**
-> ***id*** *(PRIMARY with auto increment)*
-> other

**table_1**
-> **id** *(foreign key to table zero id)*
-> varchar(80) Example value: (aahellobbb)
 
-> one_field

**table_2**
-> **id** *(foreign key to table zero id)*
-> varchar(160) Example value: (aaececehellobbb)
-> other_field

**What I want:** Search and get an (id,varchar) array containing all matches with the LIKE '%str%' on the varchar field. For example, if I search with the "hello" string, then I should get both example values with their respective ids. These ids are always going to be different, since they are references to a PRIMARY KEY.

**What I tried**: I tried with UNION ALL but it does not work with LIMITS in my example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By using `UNION` you may get several times rows with the same ID. What about using `LEFT JOIN` ?

If I've understood your question:

```
SELECT table_zero.id, table_1.varchar_field, table_2.varchar_field
FROM table_zero
  LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_zero.id = table_1.id
  LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_zero.id = table_2.id
WHERE table_1.varchar_field LIKE '%str%'
  OR table_2.varchar_field LIKE '%str%'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It works fine for me but I get a pair of two fields called "name". Each pair has one NULL value and the matched string. Is this normal? I know its due to the double table search... but, it just seems strange. Thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: If you would like only one field in your results containing the matched string, you can use `COALESCE(table_1.varchar_field, table_2.varchar_field) AS matched_string` instead of `table_1.varchar_field, table_2.varchar_field`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT table_zero.id, table_1.varchar_field, table_2.varchar_field
FROM table_zero
  LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_zero.id = table_1.id
  LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_zero.id = table_2.id
WHERE table_1.varchar_field LIKE '%str%'
  OR table_2.varchar_field LIKE '%str%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT table_zero.id AS ID, table_1.varchar_field AS field
FROM table_zero
  JOIN table_1 ON table_zero.id = table_1.id
WHERE table_1.varchar_field LIKE '%str%'
UNION
SELECT table_zero.id, table_2.varchar_field  AS field
FROM table_zero
  JOIN table_2 ON table_zero.id = table_2.id
) tbl
WHERE 
tbl.field LIKE '%str%'
```

Comment: Thanks, but Frostys one was the definitive one ;D Vote-up anyway!

Comment: Excesive use of memory, select 200.000 rows limit 0, 10 in 20 seconds when intent order by one column.